# GCE: How to create GCE default service account for deployment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create MongoDB Deployment on Deployment Manager, but it keeps throwing following error:

> > You must have the GCE default service account in order to create a deployment. Contact support for help restoring the account.

I certainly have default service account. I can create vm instances, clusters, etc..

[image]

Comment: On which step you're seeing this error?

Comment: On deploy state, @JL-HN. Where it asks to enter name and other settings.

Comment: What I suggest for now: try to deploy your MongoDB on another brand new project to see if the same error etc; if not, probably you'll need to ask support at the issue tracker by following instructions at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers; if so, we can further look into this;

Comment: @JL-HN, thanks for suggestion. I'm already running mongodb on a new projects and it works there...

Comment: Glad to hear that it works at another project; I suspect there seems sth wrong with your original project, so you can open an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com to ask the support team to take a look into the project if you still wants to find out the cause :)